How can I change the location of `.zsh_sessions` directory
The ZSH sessions directory gets created in $HOME/.zsh_sessions. How can I change this directory's location ?
Haven't found anything searching on Google and DuckDuckGo.

You will need to change the location in /etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal.  From that file:
# Set up the session directory/file.
SHELL_SESSION_DIR="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zsh_sessions"
SHELL_SESSION_FILE="$SHELL_SESSION_DIR/$TERM_SESSION_ID.session"                                                    
mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"

Note that the script tries to use $ZDOTDIR as the location and $HOME if $ZDOTDIR is not defined.  Change the location of the directory to where you want it to be.

Also note that that file seems to get overwritten with every macOS update, so you'll need to re-edit it each time.  (After every update, I get Terminal errors in every new window until I fix the line in that file which assumes you have $INSIDE_EMACS set…)

I disabled session support in bash and zsh years ago.
